# Draw2d JS How to get the figure that the port is connected to from the connection properties?

Tags: javascript, draw2d

I create in one part of code figures an connection between figures, like this:

```
    var input = figure.createPort("input");
    var output= figure.createPort("output");
```

but i also need get information about connection in other part of code.
 I have seen only **getSoucrePort()** and **getTargetPort()** In connection's properties that doesn't connected with figure. Does it any way to get source or target figure (not port) in draw2d?